# Cannot connect App Store after upgrading to Mavericks

Tags: macos

I have just upgraded my Macbook Pro to OS X 10.9 Mavericks, and then I got the problem which cannot connect to App Store even though I was trying to sign in from

Menu/Store/Sign In

[image]

Does anyone has the same problem? and how you fix it?